# Prove that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Searching for help with the following proof in real analysis.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Prove that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

My hypothesis for this solution for the proof was to prove it for the special case $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, then use a change of variables to reduce the case $[a,b]$ to this special case.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Yes, you can use a change of variables. Once you have done that , there are many ways to do this question. You can use the Bernstein Polynomials, or use the notion of convolution of functions as well. The Bernstein Polynomials are more understandable as a proof, but the convolution proof is a useful notion for the future.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг could you submit a answer with one of ways to solve for proof?

Comment: I'm curious about the source of your question, since it's a classic result in real analysis and usually taught in a course, not assigned as an exercise. Would a link to a solution online be appropriate for you?

Comment: yes either a submission or a link would be great

Comment: Search on the web for _Weierstrass approximation theorem_ or _Stone Weierstrass theorem_. Pick a link that helps you. Wikipedia has the Bernstein polynomial proof @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг refers to.

Comment: I have been searching, and was unable to come up with anything